# Improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For any $\lambda > 0$, define $f_\lambda : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_\lambda(x) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
 \lambda \cdot exp(-\lambda x) && x > 0\\
 0 && otherwise
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then calculate the (improper) integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_\lambda (x) dx$.

So the function is discontinuous in at the transition from x <= 0 to x > 0. I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_\lambda (x) dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{0} f_\lambda (x) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f_\lambda (x) dx$.

Here is the problem: To me, it seems like that the integrals from 0 to $\infty$ should not exist because there is a discontinuity here in this interval. Therefore, it seems to me that I also should use the formula for improper integrals with discontinouty, that is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{t \to a^+} \int_{t}^b f(x) dx$ where f(x) is discontinuous at $b$. Thus, in the end would have applied formulas for both types of improper integrals. Is this correct or should you just apply the formula for improper integrals at infinite intervals?

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Following what @JoséCarlosSantos was saying you can think of the integral 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$
as
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int _{\frac 1 a}^a \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \bigg[-e^{\lambda x}\bigg]_{\frac 1 a}^a$$
$$= \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} (-e^{\lambda a}+e^{-\frac \lambda a})=0+1=1$$

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it as follows:\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\lambda(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0f_\lambda(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^\infty f_\lambda(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=0+\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\left[-e^{\lambda x}\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: But why should you not also apply $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{t \to a^+} \int_{t}^b f(x) dx$ where f(x) is discontinuous at $b$? I mean isn't there is discontinuity from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: If two functions $f,g\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ are such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in(a,b]$, then $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx$. So, the fact that $f_\lambda$ is discontinuous at $0$ doesn't matter; I can deal with it as if it was equal to $e^{-\lambda x}$ for each $x\geqslant0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos shouldn't the result be $1$?

Comment: @RScrlli Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Before I accept your answer. Can you elaborate on your comment? Like why exactly this is true for my case and in that case, what if g and f?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are integrable functions from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb R$ and if$$\bigl(\forall x\in(a,b]\bigr):f(x)=g(x),$$then$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$In particular, if $f=f_\lambda$ and $g(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for each $x\geqslant0$, then$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$